# Asset pipeline not working on Rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am setting up a legacy Rails 3 project, ruby 1.9.3.

The asset pipeline is not working.

At this moment I have the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
```

Here is my development.rb file:

```
MyProj::Application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false 
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

and here is my Gemfile

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

#gem 'pg'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem "authlogic", "3.0.3"
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'fog'
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0"
gem "friendly_id", "~> 3.2.1"
gem 'activemerchant'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'i18n', '0.6.0'
gem 'ajaxful_rating_jquery', :git => "git://github.com/lshemesh/ajaxful_rating_jquery.git"
#gem 'acts_as_state_machine'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'state_machine'
#gem 'bartt-ssl_requirement', :require => 'ssl_requirement'
gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
gem 'populator', '0.2.5'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer'
gem 'braintree'
gem 'flag_shih_tzu'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'honeypot-captcha'
gem 'famfamfam_flags_rails'
gem 'language_list'
gem 'simple_captcha2', require: 'simple_captcha'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'

# group :development do
#   gem 'thin'
# end

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  # gem 'autotest-rails'
  gem 'factis'
  gem 'email_spec'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

I have the following on my application.rb

```
config.assets.enabled = true

# Add asset path to find our fonts
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "javascripts")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images")
```

And this is my application.css.scss

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require famfamfam-flags
*/
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Just as a comment, the app is being started on development environment
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000

Comment: Did you get this by downloading from the production server? Do you have `.bundle` and `vendor/bundle` folders?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded from the production server and I don't have vendor/bundle. I don't know what is .bundle

Comment: They will be folders, do you see them if you run `ls -al`?  I'm guessing you will.  Essentially the site thinks it's running in the production environment.

Comment: japed, what's that .bundle file?

Comment: It makes sense what you are saying, but why is that happening?

Comment: I ran ls -al and those folders didn't appear